LLM does not answer questions by using retrieved documents but by its training data
I am using a retrieval chain incl embeddings which I created beforehand.
The vector retriever finds some documents regarding the users questions.
But obviously the llm does not take these documents to answer the question. Instead it is using its trained data. I told the llm in the prompt to provide the sources and it offers some links instead of the retrieved documents. Does anybody know how to tell the llm to only use the retrieved documents for answering questions? Actually I thought it is given by using a ConversationalretrievalChain.
See my code below. Many thanks!
print("Setup chat model")
local_path = (
   "models/zephyr-7b-beta.Q5_K_M.gguf"
)
chat = GPT4All(
    model=local_path, 
    temp=0
)

print("Setup embeddings model")
model_name = "sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2"
model_kwargs = {'device': 'cpu'}
encode_kwargs = {'normalize_embeddings': False}
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name=model_name,
    model_kwargs=model_kwargs,
    encode_kwargs=encode_kwargs
)

print("Load embeddings database")
db = Chroma(
    persist_directory="emb/local",
    embedding_function=embeddings
)

threshold = 0.5
print("Creating the retrieval chain")
retriever = MyVectorStoreRetriever(
   vectorstore=db,
   search_type="similarity_score_threshold",
   search_kwargs={"score_threshold": threshold, "k": 3},
)

prompt_template = """Use the instructions provided below to answer the question:
 Provide the sources where you found any information.
 Context from document retriever: {context}
 Question: {question}
 """

qa_prompt=PromptTemplate(template=prompt_template, input_variables=['context', 'question'])
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True, output_key='answer', input_key="question")
chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm=chat,
    retriever=retriever,
    memory=memory,
    chain_type="stuff",
    combine_docs_chain_kwargs={'prompt': qa_prompt},
    return_source_documents=True
)

user_input=input(f"prompt:")
result=chain({'question':user_input})
answer = f"Answer:{result['answer']}\n\n"
#print retrieved documents if available
if result['source_documents']:
    sources=result['source_documents']
    len_source = len(sources)
    num_of_sources = f"Number of identified sources (similarity threshold: {int(threshold*100)}%): {len_source}\n" 
    source_list = ["file: " + source.metadata["source"] + " page: " + str(source.metadata["page"]) + " having a similarity score of: "+ str(round(source.metadata["score"] *100,2)) + "%\n" for source in sources]
    source_str = ''.join(map(str,source_list))
    source = num_of_sources + source_str 
else: source = ""
print(answer + source)

Sorry for the german text in the image. I am just asking about the planets of the solar system.

